# Xamarin Emulator name lookup failed for emulator 'emulator-5554'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I develop xamarin on remote computer and debug on local android emulator.
I use ssh tunnel to port forwarding : -N -R 5037:localhost:5037

1. On remote computer

   - adb devices is OK

     > List of devices attached
     >   emulator-5554   device
   - android-studio found emulator-5554
   - But when I use Visual Studio. Here is Xamarin Diagnostics

     > [I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
     >   [D:]:                     Tracking avd started
     >   [D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\tuanha-01.android\avd'
     >   [D:]:                     avd watcher android path: 'C:\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\android.bat'
     >   [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: emulator-5554  device
     >   [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
     >   [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
     >   [D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 getprop
     >   [D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 0 devices
     >   [E:]:                     Emulator name lookup failed for emulator 'emulator-5554'

Edit: If I use Genymotion, On remote Visual Studio can view Genymotion Emulator

> [I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
>   [D:]:                     Tracking avd started
>   [D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\tuanha-01.android\avd'
>   [D:]:                     avd watcher android path: 'C:\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\android.bat'
>   [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 192.168.31.101:5555    device
>   [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
>   [D:RunShellCommand]:      192.168.31.101:5555 getprop
>   [D:RunShellCommand]:      192.168.31.101:5555 getprop
>   [D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 0 devices

But It has error on debug

> Android application is debugging.
>   Cannot start debugging: Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:8815: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8816
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8816